# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive

Tags: java

What I am trying to do, is go through the list of items, and if the the player has one of the ITEM IDS, then it will check for the next item and so on. As of now. I get the full set, and no duplicates but when I have all 5 items. I get a bound must be positive. Note that I want players to stop getting the item aslong as they still have the full set aka all 5.
Im pretty tired right now so I cant really think. Any help is appreciated.

```
   if (Misc.random(3) == 1) {
        player.getActionSender().sendDebugMessage("hi");
        List<Item> lumberjackPossibilities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Item item : LUMBERJACK) {
            if ((item.getId() == HAT || item.getId() == TOP || item.getId() == LEGS || item.getId() == BOOTS) && itemService.playerOwnsItem(player, item.getId())) {
                continue;
            }
            lumberjackPossibilities.add(item);
        }
        Item reward = null;
        Random random = new Random();
        while (reward == null || reward.getCount() == -1) {
            int index = random.nextInt(lumberjackPossibilities.size());
            reward = lumberjackPossibilities.get(index);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It means `lumberjackPossibilities` is empty.

Comment: Nvm fixed, lol I realised that it was empty after, since I was wearing the 5 items. But all I needed to do was check if the list was not empty, and if it wasnt give them the item